# Invalidating doctrine ORM cache in a rabbitmq-consumer | Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, rabbitmq

I have a rabbitmq-consumer implemented in a symfony2 app with the [oldsound/rabbitmq-bundle](https://github.com/videlalvaro/RabbitMqBundle)
The app consumes 10 messages at a time and collects data from a mysql-db using the doctrine-querybuilder with filters given in the message-data.
Cachingsystem is APC.
Consider this stripped-down code of the query

```
$qb = $this->entityManager
    ->getRepository('My\Entity')
    ->createQueryBuilder();
$qb
    ->select('sum(this) as this, sum(that) as that')
    ->andWhere('field in (:values)')
    ->setParameter('values', $filterValues);
$result = $qb
    ->getQuery()
    ->setSingleResult();
```

This query returns 10 times the same data for the different filter-values. When the consumer restarts and consumes the next 10 messages, I get a different result 10 times again.
I think the doctrine-cache is responsible for this and tried invalidating the cache like so:

```
$qb = $this->entityManager
    ->getRepository('My\Entity')
    ->createQueryBuilder();
$qb
    ->select('sum(this) as this, sum(that) as that')
    ->andWhere('field in (:values)')
    ->setParameter('values', $filterValues);
$result = $qb
    ->getQuery()
    ->setResultCacheLifetime(0)
    ->setSingleResult();
```

But with no effect.
I can workaround this behaviour by consuming 1 message at a time only, but this slows down my app to an unacceptable degree.

May anyone hint me in the right direction?

Thanks,
jojo

Comment: We're using oldsound as well, can you try starting 10 consumers each of them consuming only 1 message at time?

Comment: I think you could use those on your query: setCacheable(bool), useResultCache(bool)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It boiled down to an error in my code. 
I somehow thought that the consumer gets re-instanciated after each message consumed. Thats not true! In my query-services, I kept the result of some querys in a class-property. Then, the code was like this:

```
<?php
if (null === $this->queryResult) {
    $this->doQuery();
} else {
    return $this->queryResult
}
```

So, after the first message was consumed, doQuery() was never executed again until the consumer got restarted. I had to reset the class-properties after each run and that fixed it for me, obviously.

Lesson learned: When you make the consumer consume more than one message in a process, bear in mind that the consumer and all services used within only initialize once and keep their state across the consumed messages.

Regards to @Francesco Panina for pointing me in the right direction. And please excuse the late reply :)